# Issue on LEMP configuration and how can i redirect to NodeJS request to NGINX

Tags: node.js, nginx

I configured a *LEMP server* on *Ubuntu* with *NodeJS* but I'm getting the following error on browser.

`"The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable`.

Please try again later." how can i redirect to *NodeJS* request to *NGINX* .Can you please help me how can i sort out these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If NGINX work through PHP-FPM (FastCGI Process Manager) then you can uncomment the important part for PHP is the  location ~ \.php$ {} stanza in the default vhost which is defined in the file

> vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

like

```
[...]

location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

[...]
```

And for NodeJS you can also modify the same Vhost file

> vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

and add lines below location ~ \.php$ {} stanza  like

```
[...]
        location /testapp/ {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
[...]
```

from this you can forwarding port to Node.js app with Nginx

```
Now you can access the your page by this URL http://localhost/testapp/ instead of http://localhost:3000/
```

Hope It will work for you